# C++ u8 literal - unexpected encoding on Windows

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17

I'm sure there's something I am missing here but I am comparing the contents of a regular string literal (in a utf8 encoded document) with a u8 string literal and on Windows the u8 encoded literal doesn't contain the expected utf8 encoded data while on Linux it does.

Details:

- cpp file is utf8 encoded
- C++17 is enabled
- compiling using vs 2019 on Windows
- compiling using gcc 9.2.1 on Linux

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct HexCharStruct {
    unsigned char c;
    HexCharStruct(unsigned char _c) : c(_c) { }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const HexCharStruct& hs) {
    return (o << std::hex << (int)hs.c);
}

inline HexCharStruct hex(unsigned char _c) {
    return HexCharStruct(_c);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    std::string s1 = "";
    std::string s2 = u8"";

    std::cout << "s1: ";
    for (const char& c : s1)
        std::cout << hex(c) << " ";
    std::cout << "\ns2: ";
    for (const char& c : s2)
        std::cout << hex(c) << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the hex values printed on Windows and Linux for s1 and s2 when I run this:

- s1 (Windows): **f0 9f 8e 82**
- s1 (Linux): **f0 9f 8e 82**
- s2 (Windows): **c3 b0 c5 b8 c5 bd e2 80 9a**
- s2 (Linux): **f0 9f 8e 82**

The utf8 hex values for  are **f0 9f 8e 82** so everything is as expected except for s2 on Windows. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Looks like double utf8 conversion of utf8 string.

Comment: Yup. The character U+00F0 is, encoded in UTF-8, the bytes 0xC3 0xB0. Your compiler is treating that u8 string like the contents are in CP-1252 or Latin-1 or another single-byte character encoding and converting that to UTF-8.

Comment: It seems (to me) that UTF-8 support is not an issue anymore in `g++` on Linux but still an issue in VS on Windows. What has ever worked for me (regardless of every system): encoding of UTF-8 sequences as octal sequences: e.g. `"\303\260"` for U+00F0 (and silently assuming that `std::string` will never contain anything else than UTF-8). That worked in the past as well as now. (But, I'm old and unflexible to adopt new features...) ;-)

Comment: Try saving your source file as UTF-8 with BOM. Without BOM, the compiler assumes system-default codepage. Or, with sufficiently recent MSVC version, use [`/utf-8' option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft compiler assumes source is ANSI-encoded, which depends on the localized version of Windows in use.  On U.S. and Western European Windows the encoding is assumed to be `Windows-1252`.

When the compiler assumes `Windows-1252`, it decodes the `UTF-8` bytes encoded in the source in the wrong encoding and thinks it is four `Windows-1252` characters, then encodes *those* characters in UTF-8.  A quick demo (Python):

```
>>> ''.encode('utf8') # bytes in the file
b'\xf0\x9f\x8e\x82'
>>> b'\xf0\x9f\x8e\x82'.decode('Windows-1252') # What the compiler reads.
'ðŸŽ‚'
>>> 'ðŸŽ‚'.encode('utf8') # What the compiler generates for u8 string.
b'\xc3\xb0\xc5\xb8\xc5\xbd\xe2\x80\x9a'
```

To use UTF-8 sources, two options are to encode the source in UTF-8 w/ BOM or add the `/utf-8` compiler switch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to continue the discussion a bit. So in this situation the compiler is assuming u8-literals are Windows-1252 encoded but is correctly assuming all the normal string literals are utf8 encoded. So it seems if the document is utf8 encoded on Windows and literals are used containing utf8 characters then the correct encoding is assumed, but if you want to use the u8 literal specifier then you require the /utf-8 compiler flag. Seems like a bug and the compiler flag is just circumventing it.

Comment: @aatwo No, in your example, `s1` will contain the bytes as encoded in the source.  The compiler assumes an encoding on reading the source, and assumes the same encoding when creating `"..."` string.  A `L"..."` or `u8"..."` string must decode the source bytes to Unicode code points using the assumed or specified source encoding, then encode those code points to UTF-16/UTF-32 (Windows/Linux) or UTF-8, respectively, so if the source encoding is incorrect, you get an incorrect result.