# MSVC is double-encoding UTF-8 strings, why?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, encoding

So, here is some simple code to recreate my issue:

```
#include <cstdio>

const char* badString = u8"ï–®ï–¶aÅ¡ð’€€"; 
const char* anotherBadString = u8"\xef\x96\xae\xef\x96\xb6\x61\xc5\xa1\xf0\x92\x80\x80";
const char* goodString = "\xef\x96\xae\xef\x96\xb6\x61\xc5\xa1\xf0\x92\x80\x80";

void printHex(const char* str)
{
    for (; *str; ++str)
    {
        printf("%02X ", *str & 0xFF);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printHex(badString);
    printHex(anotherBadString);
    printHex(goodString);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect all of these strings to print out the same result, `EF 96 AE EF 96 B6 61 C5 A1 F0 92 80 80` . However, in MSVC 2019, the first two strings print out `C3 AF C2 96 C2 AE C3 AF C2 96 C2 B6 61 C3 85 C2 A1 C3 B0 C2 92 C2 80 C2 80`. This seems to be a result of encoding into UTF-8 an extra time.

I've read in [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046071/c-u8-literal-unexpected-encoding-on-windows) that a solution to this problem is to add the `/utf-8` flag to the project, but I've tried that and it doesn't make any difference. Is there something more fundamental that I'm not understanding here?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I must admit that your exposed `goodString` is the only form I'm trusting really. It's based on ASCII characters only (not what is encoded but how it's stored in the source code file). If such files are used with varying editors and tools on varying platforms, none of these tools will cause any harm to their contents. Due to my paranoia concerning this, I even use octal sequences instead of hex as the former are limited to 3 digits, the latter may have 2 digits or more. Thus, the latter can break if hex sequences are mixed with arbitrary ASCII characters (I mean non-hex sequences).

Answer (score 1):

The first character of the first string is `ï` (U+00EF, Latin Small Letter I With Diaeresis), whose UTF-8 encoding is `C3 AF`.

You apparently want the first string to begin with U+F5AE, but whatever editor you opened the source file in agrees with MSVC that it doesn't begin with that character.

The source file is probably encoded as UTF-8 with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), and that's why the `/utf-8` flag doesn't change anything. The string was corrupted at some point, and now its corrupted form is faithfully represented in the file, and MSVC is faithfully preserving it in the compiled code.

The second string begins with `\xef`, which MSVC is interpreting as equivalent to `\u00ef`, which is `ï` again. I can't find any clear statement in the C++20 draft standard regarding what `\x` is supposed to mean in UTF-8 strings (although I didn't look very hard). From experimentation, it appears that most compilers other than MSVC treat `\x` followed by hex digits as a literal byte, even if that makes the string not valid UTF-8. I think you shouldn't use `\x` in `u8` prefixed strings because it isn't portable (except for `\x00` through `\x7f`, probably). If you want U+F5AE then write `\uf5ae`.